# “Could you imagine” or “Can you imagine”?

Tags: grammar

I have to write an essay for my english class and I wanted to start it with a question:  " Could you imagine yourself being trapped on a cage  your entire life? ". But now I don’t know whether i should use Could or Can

Comment: You have a choice (not so with 'I' and 'English'), but I'd consider 'can' appropriate here: no hedging is needed, and 'could' really fits better when conditions are specified (when hedging isn't involved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verbal modalities 'could' and 'can' are structures which can signify variable degrees of conditionality.

'Could', if being employed in a conditional clause such as 'If I could purchase a centrifuge, then I would study more botany', suggests improbability or impossibility. 
However, in a purely indicative mood, it is 'used to indicate possibility'. Conversely, can applies a more definite signification: 'have the opportunity or possibility'.

Thus, using the second conditional 'could' in your interrogative, '*could* you imagine' is preferred. It is critical to note that if your gerund phrase, 'being trapped on a cage your entire life' were more plausible (an issue for epistemology) like 'dreaming the night before', 'can' may be used.